# find target's target i.e friend of friend in force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using `D3.JS` libraries force directed graph,

I am using the following code to find target nodes

```
graph.links.forEach(function(d) {
          linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
          linkedByIndex[d.target.index + "," + d.source.index] = 1;
                  });
    });


    function neighboring(a, b) {
      return a.index == b.index || linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
    }
```

How can I find and highlight target's target ? Can anybody help me with this ?

**EDIT:**

Solved the problem in the following way:

First created the adjacent matrix:

```
var adjMat=null;
var adjMatSq=null;


adjMat=new Array(graph.nodes.length);
        for(var i = 0;i < graph.nodes.length; ++i)
        {
            adjMat[i]=new Array(graph.nodes.length);            
            for(var j = 0; j < graph.nodes.length; ++j)
            {
                adjMat[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
```

Then assigned the values to the adjacent matrix:

```
graph.links.forEach(function(d) {
          adjMat[d.source.index][d.target.index] = adjMat[d.target.index][d.source.index] = 1;
          adjMat[d.source.index][d.source.index] = 1; 
        });

        adjMatSq=matrixMultiply(adjMat, adjMat);
    });
```

Then I found the square of matrix so that I'll be able to get the second degree nodes:

```
function matrixMultiply(m1,m2)
        {
            var result = [];
          for(var j = 0; j < m2.length; j++) {
            result[j] = [];
            for(var k = 0; k < m1[0].length; k++) {
                var sum = 0;
              for(var i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
                    sum += m1[i][k] * m2[j][i];
                }
                result[j].push(sum);
            }
        }
        return result;
        }
```

Defined a function to find the second degree nodes:

```
    function areAtSecondDegree(a,c)
    {
        return adjMatSq[a.index][c.index] == 1;
    }
```

[My Code Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GCDR8nVZnBBVDyDIUV2X?p=preview)

Comment: You have to call `neighboring` recursively, i.e. for the initial node and then for all its neighbours.

Comment: In this `d3.selectAll(".link").transition().duration(500)
        .style("opacity", function(o) {
        return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : .1;
      });` as I am highlighting neighbours and `d3.selectAll(".node").transition().duration(500)
        .style("opacity", function(o) {
           return neighboring(d, o) ? 1 : .1;
        });`
changing opacity. But what I am not able to get to how to call a function recursively from returned value in javascript ?

Comment: You would need to filter the data explicitly to get the adjacent nodes through something like `neighbours = data.filter(function(o) { return o.source == d || o.target == d; });`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff above is my code for what I have tried, but the problem I am having is even after calling `areAtSecondDegree` and `areFriends`  I am not able to display just the two level connections. and also I am having problem that I am not able to display second level links by adjacency matrix. Can you guide me with this procedure ?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff the problem is that my functions are working fine but, I don't understand how to use those for to change the opacity and style's of the links and nodes

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Can you please guide me that where I am going wrong ? how can I solve this problem ? as I am able to find the second level connection but unable to use it as a style or opacity factor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principle is as follows. Given a specific node, determine its immediate neighbours. To get second degree neighbours, take this list of neighbours you have just determined, and for each get the list of neighbours again. The union of all those lists is the list of first and second degree neighbours.

In code this could look like this:

```
var connected = {};
  var friends = graph.nodes.filter(function(o) { return areFriends(d, o); });
  friends.forEach(function(o) {
      connected[o.name] = 1;
      // second pass to get second-degree neighbours
      graph.nodes.forEach(function(p) {
        if(areFriends(o, p)) {
          connected[p.name] = 1;
        }
      });
  });
```

If you want to have arbitrary n degree neighbours, you would need to change this to accommodate the fact that you don't know how many iterations of this to run.

Complete demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/H52r5gRUXuk7WXTD7lXH?p=preview).